# Python BaseHTTPRequestHandler - Como inserir caminho correto das imagens

Tags: python

Quando crio uma aplicação Web em python, mas sem usar Frameworks, apenas usando as classes HTTPServer e BaseHTTPRequestHandler, como insiro uma imagem? Esse é o código:

https://pastebin.com/W6iPK2P2

No mesmo diretório que está meu arquivo PY, tenho uma pasta img com a imagem dentro. Porém a imagem não aparece. Como deve ser minha variável 'imagem' pra que a imagem apareça corretamente?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bom dia. vc tem q fazer uma validação da extenção dos arquivos para retornar o minetype correto segue um ex retirado da net que funciona:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
from os import curdir, sep

PORT_NUMBER = 8080

#This class will handles any incoming request from
#the browser 
class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    
    #Handler for the GET requests
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path=="/":
            self.path="/index_example2.html"

        try:
            #Check the file extension required and
            #set the right mime type

            sendReply = False
            if self.path.endswith(".html"):
                mimetype='text/html'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".jpg"):
                mimetype='image/jpg'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".gif"):
                mimetype='image/gif'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".js"):
                mimetype='application/javascript'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".css"):
                mimetype='text/css'
                sendReply = True

            if sendReply == True:
                #Open the static file requested and send it
                f = open(curdir + sep + self.path) 
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type',mimetype)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(f.read())
                f.close()
            return


        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)

try:
    #Create a web server and define the handler to manage the
    #incoming request
    server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
    print 'Started httpserver on port ' , PORT_NUMBER
    
    #Wait forever for incoming htto requests
    server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print '^C received, shutting down the web server'
    server.socket.close()
```

fonte: https://github.com/tanzilli/playground/blob/master/python/httpserver/example2.py

uma outra forma é vc retornar o o jpg como binário
no endswitch das imagens seria assim para jpg

```
if self.path.endswith(".jpg"):
    f = open(applicationPath + '/' + self.path, 'rb')
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type','image/jpg')
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(f.read())
    f.close()
    return
```

Comment: Mas a minha intenção não é trazer a imagem diretamente. É que depois vou usar templates HTML, assim preciso trazer um conteúdo HTML normal e que tenha uma tag 'img'. Dai nesse caso não estou sabendo o que colocar na propriedade 'src' pra que a imagem seja carregada.

Comment: entao o primeiro ex que eu te enviei funciona dessa forma. ele so va processar a extenção do arquivo para que retorne o mimetype correto e vc pode inserir em seu html a imagem

Comment: Verdade, eu não havia entendido. Tive que fazer umas modificações pra rodar no Python 3, mas funcionou!
Também tive que fazer uma condição pra quando for HTML, pois dai o Jinja tem que processar o template. Mas no fim deu certo.
Obrigado!